# Replace td tag with regex

Tags: c#, html, regex, xml-parsing

How can I replace a certain part in a html string variable with a definied string?

```
var htmlvar = "<td style=\"border-width: 0px;\" align=\"left\" id=\"tdPassword\">@Model.Password</td>"
```

that the result looks like that:

```
var htmlvar = "<td style=\"border-width: 0px;\" align=\"left\" id=\"tdPassword\">*******</td>"
```

I'm using c# .net 3.5 and I thougt of a regex solution.

Comment: Use the html agility pack: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/300011

Comment: @EgeÖzcan the "Even Jon Skeet cannot parse HTML using regular expressions" part always make me LOL

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
(?<start>\<td[^\>]*\>)[^\<]*(?<end></td>)
```

to match, and

```
$1****$2
```

for replacement.

Comment: i used this comment:     Use the html agility pack: htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com – David Brabant 3 hours ago

Comment: You used best way. I assumed you are consist on simple regex.

Answer (score 0):

i used this comment content to solve it:
Use the html agility pack: htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com – David Brabant 3 hours ago
thanks